# To use pointers or not to use in these situations?

Tags: go

I'm building a (deep parser?) and have two parts of the code, in each of those I have two ways to work with pointers:

**The first part:**

```golang
// The first way
struct User {
    client   http.Client,
    jar      cookiejar.Jar,
    username string,
    password string,
}
func NewUser(username, password string) *User {
    jar := cookiejar.New(nil)
    client := http.Client{ Jar: &jar }
    return &User{ username: username, password: password, client: client, jar: jar }
}

// The second way
struct User {
    client   &http.Client, //!
    jar      &cookiejar.Jar, //!
    username string,
    password string,
}
func NewUser(username, password string) *User {
    jar := &cookiejar.New(nil) //!
    client := &http.Client{ Jar: jar } //!
    return &User{ username: username, password: password, client: client, jar: jar } //!
}
```

(Changed lines have a comment `//!` in the end)

**The second part:**

```golang
func (u *User)process() {
    u.client.Get("https://example.com")
    fmt.Printf("%v", u.jar.Cookies("https://example.com"))
}

// The first way
users := make([]&User, 256)
// ... setting users
for user := range users {
    go user.process()
}

// The second way
users := make([]User, 256) //!
// ... setting users
for user := range users {
    go user.process()
}
```

Which way is better for each part and why?
Or is there an even better way to do all this?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. You have 2 "first way"s, 2 "second way"s and 2 code samples with an unclear relationship to each other. It's also not clear what your objective / requirements are, or how any of this is related to parsing.

Comment: These are possible pieces of the code

Comment: Two ways to implement User struct and two ways to work with it

Comment: Considering that both options are invalid, I would go with "none of the above"

Answer (score 1):

The main point of using pointers in containers is that it when the container is copied, the pointed-to value is not copied. If the copying of an object is either not safe (like a mutex), or too expensive (like a large array), then it could be a good idea to use a pointer.

In your case, you are storing your users in a slice. It's important to remember with slices that any time you `append` on the slice, it may or may not copy the entire slice contents. This means that if you are ever to use `append` (or `copy`, or other methods of copying the values), your data type *must* be copy-safe: either by making the data type copy-safe in itself, or by using a pointer to it.

If there is no issue with copying the values, then you may as well use non-pointer values, as it will simplify your program:

- Zero-values will be usable (instead of nil)
- Fewer allocations required
- Simplify or eliminate constructor code

If your slice does not need to be copied (`append` or otherwise), and you only use `User` values by calling this `process` method which takes a pointer receiver, then no copies will occur and you have nothing to worry about.

If copies may occur then the question is: is your `User` struct copy-safe? Most likely, yes. The http.Client documentation doesn't have any specific note about not being copy-safe, so it would only be unsafe if you directly modify one of its [fields](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client).

Here's what a simplified version of your code might look like:

```golang
type User struct {
    client   http.Client
    username string
    password string
}


func (u *User) setup() {
    user.username = something
    user.password = something
    user.client.Jar, err := cookiejar.New(nil)
    if err != nil {
        // handle error somehow
    }
}

func (u *User) process() {
    // do some request
    fmt.Println(u.client.Jar.Cookies("https://example.com"))
}

func run() {
    users := make([]User, 256)
    for _, user := range users {
        user.setup()
        go user.process()
    }
    // do something ...
}
```

If you're unsure about if your `User` type is or will be copy-safe, you can simply change to slice of pointers and continue using pointer-receiver methods and you will be fine.

```golang
func run() {
    users := make([]*User, 256)
    for i := range users {
        users[i] = new(User)
        users[i].setup()
        go users[i].process()
    }
    // do something ...
}
```

Comment: Should I do use a pointer to `http.Client` (`client *http.Client`) instead of saving it by value, as you did in `struct User`?

Comment: @Wynell There's not any particular reason why you would need to. I tried to address this in the answer already, but if there is any part of it that is unclear I will try to clarify.